# Developer, Digital Premature, Apple Enthusiast

Tags: flutter-audioplayers

I am checking out the flutter audioplayers package. It does work very well for multiple simultaneous audio files, but I couldn't figure out how to play then so that they play exactly in sync. Any hints? Thank you very much.

I created several AudioPlayer Instances, one per audio file. Then I started them, but they are not exactly in sync due to the delay in starting them (I have 14 Tracks).